# how to open a dialog in material-ui on button click

Tags: reactjs, redux, material-ui

```
export default class Help extends Component {
    componentWillMount(){
        this.state = {open:false};
    }


    handleOpen() {
        this.setState({open: true});
    }

    handleClose() {
        this.setState({open: false});
    }

    render() {
        const actions = [
      <FlatButton
        label="Cancel"
        primary={true}
        onTouchTap={this.handleClose}
      />,
      <FlatButton
        label="Submit"
        primary={true}
        keyboardFocused={true}
        onTouchTap={this.handleClose}
      />,
    ];
        return (
            <div className="container-fluid">
                <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary active" id="Hlp" onTouchTap={this.handleOpen}>Help</button>
                <Dialog
                    title="Dialog With Actions"
                    actions={actions}
                    modal={false}
                    open={this.state.open}
                    onRequestClose={this.handleClose}
                    >
                    The actions in this window were passed in as an array of React objects.
                </Dialog>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

I ve to open a dialog using material-ui for button click, Right now I see a an error in console, saying Cannot read property 'prepareStyles' of undefined..I could see button on screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you omitted them from your snippet only, but make sure in your real code that you have the proper material-ui imports at the top:

```
import Dialog from 'material-ui/Dialog';
import FlatButton from 'material-ui/FlatButton';
```

Comment: I did notinclude the importa buts its sure that those imports are presenr

Comment: OK. In your topmost component (or some other parent component), are you wrapping with the MuiThemeProvider per the instructions? http://www.material-ui.com/#/get-started/usage

Comment: Do we need to add this muitheme for every component??

Comment: No - just on the topmost component (like your "App" or similar component in which all your other components are children, grandchildren, etc). Additional tip: if you want to make your custom components look and feel like material-ui by using its theme colors and other styles, you can export your class wrapped in the muiThemeable Higher-Order Component (see here, about 2/3 way down: http://www.material-ui.com/#/customization/themes )